# How to use location distance / proximity filter with facet search api

Tags: location, search

I am using [location](https://www.drupal.org/project/location), [gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap), [facet api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) modules and I have created search page for node with facet api. I want to use distance / proximity filter for facet search but I didn't get distance / proximity fields in facet search.

I used another modules like [geofield](https://www.drupal.org/project/geofield) and [address field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield), but I get all fields like address, country, zip code except distance / proximity field.

I did searched lots of solution but I didn't get right solution.
When we create normal view with content type then distance / proximity filter shows in fields and filter criteria.

regards
Arvind